# export .htaccess variable to shell or script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess file, I have this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.sh?sub=$1`
Is there anyway to show the value of $1 in the shell
command like `echo $sub`
or can I pass $1 as a parameter to script.sh?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an *environment variable* - is that readable from your script? For example, to set an environment variable called `MY_VARIABLE` to the value of the `$1` backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.sh?sub=$1 [E=MY_VARIABLE:$1,L]
```

I've also added the `L` (`last`) flag just in case. Maybe you can remove the `?sub=$1` part if it's not being used?

Comment: I tried tried this way, but when executing echo $MY_VARIABLE from the shell, I don't get a value for the variable.

Comment: In the above example `MY_VARIABLE` is an _environment_ variable, not an ordinary script variable so you may need to use whatever method your (shell) script uses for accessing _environment variables_. eg. `printenv MY_VARIABLE`.